# What can be said about the cube-free part of $x^3 -3xy^2 +y^3$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, computer-algebra

For $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbf{Z}$, not both zero, let $cfp(x,y)$ be the cube-free part of $x^3 -3xy^2 + y^3$ (normalized to be $> 0$). One sees:

(#) $cfp(x,y)$ is either a product of primes $p$, with each $p$ being 1 or 8 mod 9, or 3 times such a product.

I'd like information about which cube-free integers satisfying (#) can be written as $cfp(x,y)$. More specifically:

Questions:

(1) Is every cube-free integer satisfying (#) so representable? What about $p$ or $3p$ when $p$ is a prime that's 1 or 8 mod 9?

(2) Consider the proportion of cube-free elements of $N$ that are $< M$ and can be written as $cfp(x,y)$ to cube-free elements of $N$ that are $< M$ and satisfy (#). What happens to this proportion as $M\rightarrow\infty$? (Again the same question can be asked when attention is restricted to elements of $N$ that are $p$ or $3p$ as in (1).)

(3)   I have doubts that much is known about (2), but can anyone provide guesses, based on computer calculation, as to what the situation might be?

Comment: Why is p equal 1 or 8 mod 9, or 3 times that?

Comment: @Dabed   You can assume x and y are coprime. If either is divisible by 3, or  x and y are both 1 mod 3, or both 2 mod 3, x^3 - 3*x*y^2 + y^3 is prime to 3. When 3 divides x+y, 9 divides x^3 +y^3, and so x^3 -3*x*y^2 +y^3 is 3 or 6 mod 9.

Comment: @Dabed    I was cut short--I'll finish up. It remains to show that no p that's 7,4,2 or 5 mod 9 divides our F(x,y). If p is 7 or 4 mod 9, then (Z/p)* contains a subgroup {1,u,v} of order 3. Also, u is not a cube in Z/p--adjoining a cube root  w of u to Z/p gives a degree 3 extension. Let t be the element (w) + (1/w) of this extension. Then t^3 = u + v + 3*t, and so t^3 -3*t +1 =0. If this last equation had a root in Z/p, then w would satisfy a degree 2 equation over Z/p, which is impossible. The argument is the same when p is 2 or 5 mod 9, but now we use the field of p^2 elements ; not Z/p.

Answer (score 5):

The approach taken by Bhargava, Alpoge, and Shnidman ([Integers expressible as the sum of two rational cubes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.10730)) seems to be able to answer your question. In particular, they show that a positive portion of integers can be expressed as the sum of two rational cubes, and a positive proportion cannot be so expressed. Their argument basically boils down to a good estimate on the average rank of genus 1 curves of the shape $x^3 + y^3 = n$ as $n$ varies. Levent gave a talk on this paper last year at Banff, but I seem to recall that they did have to make use the shape of $x^3 + y^3$ significantly, and even small perturbations in the coefficients of the binary cubic form seems to make the problem hard enough as to necessitate some new ideas. I am not sure how hard it would be to make their arguments work for $x^3 - 3xy^2 - y^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the first several primes  $p$  and numbers $3p$ for which I haven't found  an expression yet.

$$ 89  ,   107    , 219 ,    271 ,    327  ,   397 ,    431 ,    433 ,    449 ,    467 ,    523  ,   537  ,   543  ,   557  ,   593  ,   597 ,    647 ,    683,     719  ,   773 ,    807 ,    829 ,    863  ,   881  ,   919 ,    921 ,    991  ,  1077 ,   1117 , $$

Comment: In fact, $89$ and $107$ and probably most of the others on this list do not occur. The curve $x^{3} - 3xy^{2} - y^3 = 89z^{3}$ represents a $3$-torsion element of the Shafarevich-Tate group of the rank zero elliptic curve $y^{2} - 801y = x^{3}$. (Note that $863$ and $881$ do occur. We get $863$ with $x = 89$, $y = 305$ and we get $881$ with $x = 49$, $y = 228$.)

Comment: @JeremyRouse  thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy Rouse   I discovered that part 1 of my question is an old one--Selmer calls the equation I was looking at "Sylvester's" equation.  After reading your comment I thought that Will hadn't searched far enough in looking for solutions for 3p when p is 179, 269 or 359--after all each of these p is a sum of two rational cubes. (When one consults Elkies tables one finds that the fundamental solution to x^3 + y^3 =p has large height in all three cases). My suspicions were confirmed when I looked at table 3 on page 351 of Selmer's opus--he lists the solutions. Will was right about the rest.

Comment: @Paul, which book by Selmer  do you mean?  There seem to be a few.

Comment: @Will    I meant the 1951 Acta Arithmetica article--not a book, but more than 100 pages. The tables all come at the end.

Comment: @Paul, thank you.